# Proxy problems on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, openssl

I'm running selenium tests using java. 
I have configured google chrome using the following code:

```
  private void configureChromeOptions() {
    File file = new File(appParams.getDrivers().getChromeDriverPath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

    chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setBinary(appParams.getDrivers().getChromeBinariesPath());
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    //Turns off multiple download warning
    prefs.put("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", Integer.valueOf(1));
    //Turns off download prompt
    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", Boolean.valueOf(false));
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", Integer.valueOf(0));
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", System.getProperty("user.home"));
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
    proxy.setSslProxy(System.getProperty("https.proxyHost"));
    logger.info("Configuring proxy with: ", System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));

    chromeCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    chromeCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
  }
```

But when I try to access the webpage, I get the following error:

```
"This site can’t be reached www.mywebsite.com is currently unreachable. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE null Reload Details Check your Internet connection Check any cables and reboot any routers, modems, or other network devices you may be using. Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings. If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the network, try removing it from the list and adding it again. If you use a proxy server… Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings… > Change proxy settings… and make sure your configuration is set to "no proxy" or "direct." www.mywebsite.com is currently unreachable."
```

If I try to access the same webpage via curl, I have no problem, as long as I use the keys:

```
curl --proxy localhost:13128 -L -k --cert mycert.crt --key mycert.key -u username:password https://www.mywebsite.com
```

This has access without any problem. I'm using cntlm to do the proxy authentication. 
The same code runs without problem inside a docker image.

What could be causing this proxy problem?

Comment: Import certificate to Chrome and load selenium with browser profile to which was certificate imported.

Comment: @pburgr, I can't import the certificates to chrome, because this executes on a linux server where I can't open the chrome to do that. I configured it to accept SSL certificates with this code (https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/handling-security-certificates-chrome-and-ie-browser-using-webdriver), but still having the same problem.

Comment: '...this executes on a linux server where I can't open the chrome to do that' maybe this is the main cause.

Comment: @pburgr, same code runs without problem inside a docker image, with the same configurations.